# Jquery Toggle If statement

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run a function when the state of the toggle is only "open". Right now the function runs either way. I'm not entirely sure how to make it so that it only runs when the toggle is opened. I found the toggle code somewhere and used it, it works great.

```
$( "#SB2p" ).click(function() {
        $( "#SB2" ).toggle('slow',function(){
            var $link = $("#SB2p");
            $(this).is(":visible") ? $link.text("<<<") : $link.text(">>>");
        });
        accumulative();
    });
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a working example.  The ternary operator uses $(this).is(':visible'), so use that:

```
   $( "#SB2p" ).click(function() {
        $( "#SB2" ).toggle('slow',function(){
            var $link = $("#SB2p");
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
              $link.text("<<<");
              accumulative();
            } else {
              $link.text(">>>");
            }
        });       
    });
```

Comment: Only issue is that it's in an asynchronous callback function, so the function will be executes a little later than the example given.

Comment: The callback function is called once the animation is ***complete***.

Comment: That's right, and that would be later than when the element is clicked, which is when the function is called in the given example, but it doesn't really matter, it clearly works for the OP.

Comment: Actually, it's exactly how I read the question.  It says to only run the function when the toggle is open, not when it is opening or when it should open.  The click event to me is the wrong time to determine if the toggle is open.  BTW, I still upvoted your answer before providing mine.

Comment: Typo sry.  It was missing curly brace before else.